# Options in Native.loadLibrary

Tags: java, jna

I have been working on `JNA` for some time now. But there is one thing, I haven't understood. For example, while loading a library:

```
Map<String, Integer> options = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
options.put(Library.OPTION_CALLING_CONVENTION, StdCallLibrary.STDCALL_CONVENTION);
this.EDSDK = (EdSdkLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("EDSDK/dll/EDSDK.dll", EdSdkLibrary.class, options);
```

What exactly is the `options` above?

The [api](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.util.Map%29) says:

> public static Object loadLibrary(String name,
>                                    Class interfaceClass,
>                                    Map options)
>
> Load a library interface from the given shared library, providing the explicit interface class and a map of options for the library. If no library options are detected the map is interpreted as a map of Java method names to native function names.
>   If name is null, attempts to map onto the current process.

Above what does `map of options for the library` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a map that holds the options for the library.   One such option is a function mapper. 
Below you can find an example:

```
    System.setProperty("jna.library.path","SiUSBXp.dll");
    HashMap<String, StdCallFunctionMapper> optionMap = new HashMap<String,    StdCallFunctionMapper>();
    StdCallFunctionMapper myMapper = new StdCallFunctionMapper();
    optionMap.put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, myMapper);
    INSTANCE = (SiUSBXp) Native.loadLibrary("SiUSBXp", SiUSBXp.class, optionMap);
```

Comment: I am sorry but what do you mean by `map that holds the mapping functions in the library.`?

Comment: it means the names of the methods

Comment: Early releases of JNA used the `Map` in place of the function mapper option.  The `Map` keys are the Java methods and the values are the mapped native methods.

Comment: `System.setProperty("jna.library.path","SiUSBXp.dll")` saved my life.